# can I optimize code size with keil uvision

Tags: optimization, compilation, keil

I'm compiling a project with keil uvision (free version). I got the following error:

```
.\_build\test.axf: error: L6047U: The size of this image (32992 bytes) exceeds the maximum allowed for this version of the linker
```

is there any flag to optimize code footprint just like `-Ospace` with ARM compiler?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124936849.htm), `-Ospace` is the default behavior unless you explicitely told the compiler to use `-Otime` instead. Open the configuration in the Menu `Project->Options for target something->C/C++`. You can also change the optimization level (-O0 to -O3) which could result in a smaller program. If the limit is 32768 bytes, it may fit!

Answer (score 1):

L6050U: The code size of this image exceeds the maximum allowed for this version...

1-) If you haven't registered the product you use an Evaluation-version. With this version installed you have crossed the code size limitation of your project. It is necessary to purchase the product at your local distributor.

2-) If you have registered the product there still might exist information of a former Evaluation-version installation in some of your project Object-files. Remove all your projects object files and rebuild the complete project by pressing F7.

3-) If you have registered MDK for 7 or 30 days and your license has expired this error message may also comes up. In this case you can return to the original Eval-version by removing the line LIC0=... at C:\Keil_V5\Tools.ini

4-) Another reason can be that you have selected a device from an architecture different than the ones supported by your fully-licensed product. Switch to a product that supports your selected device.